# What's the optimal setup for Cluedo: The Great Museum Caper?

Tags: cluedo-the-great-mystery-caper

Has the math been done on an optimal setup of security cameras and painting locations in [Cluedo: The Great Museum Caper](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1484/clue-great-museum-caper)...?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if anyone has actually used math to calculate the optimal strategy. That would of course require the correct play strategy for the camera strategy to really be the "optimal". This person has a thorough explanation of a strategy including the why.

http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/598248/pretty-hard-to-beat-4-player-setup

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best camera set-up is the one that sees the most squares.  If this is so then having one camera in each corner of the hall around the central white room with two in the room looking through the doors.